# Did not get an answer from recruiter after interviews day

Tags: interviewing

I had an interview day with a big international company for a position that includes relocation. The interview was offsite in my current country of residence. There were several people interviewing at the same time (individually). Before the interview day, at its start, and at its end, we were told we would get results by the end of the week.

The interview day was on the previous Tuesday, I've waited until Friday and did not get an answer. On Monday morning (on the recruiter's time zone) I sent an email to my recruiter asking them when I can expect to get an answer. As of now, I have not received an answer regarding the result of the interview day nor the email I sent asking when I'm expected to get an answer.

On the interview day itself, the recruiter I was in contact with wasn't present, but another recruiter was. I've been in contact only with my recruiter, and the organizer of the event before the interview and have only their contact information. I've found the LinkedIn account of the recruiter that was present on the day, but haven't contacted them.

How should I proceed?

<sup>* - There is a 10 hour time difference between me and the recruiter (their 8am is my 6pm).</sup>

<sup>** - I don't know the other people who interviewed with me and don't have a way to ask them if they got a response.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If it's a recruitment organization you should be able to call in and get a status update just fine.  They may not know anything, but should be able to tell you the status as "waiting on company" or something like that.  I have waited upwards of 3 months before and still selected, so sometimes it takes awhile.  If it was the company itself, pestering might not be so great, but if you have a recruitment company feel free to reach out to them on status knowing that it might be nothing but more waiting.

As far as time zones go there should be a main number for the recruitment agency that you can call which will have hours of operation.  If you are calling specific people via linkedIn or bypassing the professional recruitment agency I would avoid doing that and go through the correct professional channels.

**Edit based on comment**:
Duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: This wasn't through a recruitment company, it was directly through the company.

Comment: Then I think this is a duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p as david k mentioned...